# Android acra exception

Tags: android, acra

I just set up ACRA for exception reporting on Android, and on my local simulator, I get this exception:

and here is my class:

```
package com.problemio;

import android.app.Application;

import org.acra.*;

    import org.acra.annotation.*;

    @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "...")
    public class MyApplication extends Application
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() 
        {
            // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
            ACRA.init(this);
            super.onCreate();
        }

    }
```

How should I change the code to make it right?  Thanks!!!

Comment: Well such spread sheet does not exist, or at least when I point my browser to the address `https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=0AteWveJtbl4GdDA2WWsyRE5NbEtJM2hmbmd5NVhxM3c&amp;ifq` it says so.

Comment: Hmmm, this is my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AteWveJtbl4GdDA2WWsyRE5NbEtJM2hmbmd5NVhxM3c#gid=0

Comment: I also updated my question to have the code in it as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please try with form key without the suffix `#gid=0`.

Comment: Fixed it - thank you - your original comment was helpful.  I am going to sleep now - its 5:11am here :) but you can asnwer my Q and I will accept it tomorrow when I wake up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment an answer, because it solved the issue:

Such spread sheet does not exist, or at least when I point my browser to [this address](https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=0AteWveJtbl4GdDA2WWsyRE5Nb%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BEtJM2hmbmd5NVhxM3c&ifq)  (`https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=0AteWveJtbl4GdDA2WWsyRE5Nb‌​EtJM2hmbmd5NVhxM3c&amp;ifq`) it says so. Make sure you have the form key entered correctly.

Comment: Hi Boris, Trying to follow the instructions to setup the key.  What relates the formkey to excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @CodeDroid - when you create your form it is automatically assigned a key (you can see it if you look at the url you use to view the form). afterwards this key can be used to post responses to your form. Btw the url parameter is `key` not `formkey`.